# Relacionamento de uma coluna para várias

Tags: java, entity-framework, hibernate, jpa, entidade-relacionamento

Tenho uma classe entidade de nome Medico, na qual possui uma coluna IDMedico. Ela se relaciona com a classe entidade Atendimento, que por sua vez possui uma coluna IDmedico, que seria uma chave estrangeira dessa primeira.

Há também nessa tabela, Atendimento, uma outra coluna chamada IDMedicoIndica, que tambem é uma chave estrangeira da coluna IDMedico da entidade Medico. Ou seja, na tabela Medico possue apenas uma coluna com ID dos médicos e no atendimento eu preciso ter o id do médico que executa e do que indica.

Quando tento relacionar da mesma forma que fiz com o IDMedico, porém mudando o nome da coluna, me é retornado um erro dizendo que não foi possível encontrar a coluna IDMedicoIndica na entidade Medico. Como posso proceder e qual a melhor prática nesse caso?

Segue os código:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Sis_Medico")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "IDMedico", referencedColumnName = "IDPessoa")
public class Sis_Medico extends Sis_Pessoa {

    @Column(name = "IDMedico", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long IDMedico;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "medico", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Sis_Atendimento> atendimentos = new ArrayList<>();

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "medicoIndica", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<Sis_Atendimento> atendimentosIndica = new ArrayList<>();

@Entity
@Table(name = "Sis_Atendimento")
public class Sis_Atendimento {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "IDAtendimento")
    private Long idAtendimento;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDMedico", 
                referencedColumnName = "IDMedico",
                foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "SisMedico_SisAtendimento"))
    private Sis_Medico medico;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "IDMedicoIndica", 
                referencedColumnName = "IDMedico",
                foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "SisMedico_SisAtendimento"))
    private Sis_Medico medicoIndica;
```

O código assim faz até o deploye roda, mas o problema é que quando eu tento chamar a coluna IDMedicoIndica do Atendimento em uma @Query ele dá erro.

```
@Query("select Atendimento.idAtendimento, Atendimento.dataAtendimento, \n"
            + "paciente.IDPaciente, medico.IDMedico, Atendimento.IDMedicoIndica, Atendimento.desativado \n" 
            + "from Sis_Atendimento Atendimento")
```

Comment: Pode postar seus códigos (anotações )?

Comment: Posso sim, vamos lá:

Answer (score 0):

Ao usar entidades do JPA e escrever um JPQL, você precisa referenciar os nomes das colunas na entidade e não o nome das colunas na tabela, **a não ser** que você queira fazer uma consulta nativa (*native query*).

Se o seu desejo é rodar um SQL e não um JPQL, basta incluir o atributo `nativeQuery` com o valor `true` e usar os nomes reais das tabelas e colunas:

```
@Query("select Atendimento.idAtendimento, Atendimento.dataAtendimento, "
        + "Atendimento.IDMedico, Atendimento.IDMedicoIndica, Atendimento.desativado " 
        + "from Sis_Atendimento Atendimento", nativeQuery = true)
```

Se o seu desejo é usar JPQL, faça:

```
@Query("select at.idAtendimento, at.dataAtendimento, "
        + "medico.IDMedico, at.IDMedicoIndica, at.desativado " 
        + "from Sis_Atendimento at JOIN at.medico medico", nativeQuery = true)
```

PS.: removi a parte do `paciente.IDPaciente` por não ter compartilhado o relacionamento de paciente com o restante das tabelas, mas a ideia é a mesma.